# How to change width of Searchbar in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

It's being overwritten when I change the width: 83.33333333%

How do I change the width being overwritten?

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) .col-md-10 {
  width: 83.33333333%;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) .col-md-1,
.col-md-10,
.col-md-11,
.col-md-12,
.col-md-2,
.col-md-3,
.col-md-4,
.col-md-5,
.col-md-6,
.col-md-7,
.col-md-8,
.col-md-9 {
  float: left;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) .col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: well, there is no need to change the width of col-* used by bootstrap ... if 
 you ended doing so then your are doing wrong and your are not correctly using bootstrap

Comment: ok so why is it when i use chrome console its giving me the width of the search bar is in bootstrap.min.css forgive im very novice at best with this, i paid for a script and im trying to change it up a little

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you should NOT change the bootstrap css files and classes.

If you want to change something in your layout, create a new stylesheet and add it after every other css file.
HTML/CSS is parsed from top to bottom. Rules that are defined at the bottom overwrite rules that are on the top.

If you want to change a single `<div/>` for example, you should give that an id (note that ids should be unique in your document!) or a class.

If a div in your layout has a `col-*` class, you should not change its size manually, as other parts of your template could rely on it and you could destroy your entire layout and/or responsiveness.

Comment: okay Thank You i will change it all back, but shouldn't it have A css file for me to edit the width of A Search bar already i just want to change the size of it?

Comment: bootstrap provides this styles in a css file, yes. But you should not change it here! If you only want to change the size of the search bar, you can also overwrite only the size. (just extend the css class in your new css file.)